# Trouble using sbteclipse

Tags: sbt, sbteclipse

I get the following message when I try to run sbt:

[warn]          com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:2.1.0-M2 (sbtVersion=0
.12, scalaVersion=2.9.2)
[warn]
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-
plugin;2.1.0-M2: not found

I am running sbt 0.12.3.  If I need to use an earlier version of sbt with this plugin, I don't know how to find them.  The site doesn't seem to have sbt 0.12 listed for installing.

My plugins file says:
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0-M2")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.  I solved my own issue.  My plugins.sbt file had said:
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0-M2")

I changed it to: 
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.2")